# Window.xts in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, time-series, window, xts

Why does window.xts not work in parLapply? The below code gives me error:

"Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
8 nodes produced errors; first error: invalid time / time based class"

```
library(parallel)
z <- xts(11:15, as.Date(31:35))
testfun <- function(input,x){
  window(input, start = 32, end = 34) + x
}
cl <- makeCluster(8)

clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(xts)
})

clusterExport(cl, c("testfun"))
clusterExport(cl, c("z"))
r_1 <- parLapply(
  cl = cl,
  X = 1:8,
  fun = testfun,
  input = z)


stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the same error without parallelization;

```
> library(xts)
> z <- xts(11:15, as.Date(31:35))
> y <- window(z, start = 32, end = 34)
Error in .toPOSIXct(start, tzone(x)) : invalid time / time based class
```